# Cakephp: Find order by related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have two models: Event and Date. A Event hasMany Date. I want to order the events by the most recent dates. For example:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Event 1
                )

            [Date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [date] => 2015-02-05
                            [start_time] => 06:00:00
                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                            [evento_id] => 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [date] => 2015-02-06
                            [start_time] => 06:00:00
                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                            [evento_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Event 2
                )

            [Date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [date] => 2015-02-11
                            [start_time] => 06:00:00
                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                            [event_id] => 2
                        )    
                )

        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Event 3
                )

            [Date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [date] => 2015-02-02
                            [start_time] => 06:00:00
                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                            [event_id] => 3
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [date] => 2015-02-03
                            [start_time] => 06:00:00
                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                            [event_id] => 3
                        )

                )

        )
```

So, the order I want to retrieve the events are: **Event 3, Event 1, Event 2**.

This is how I'm calling the find method:

```
$this->Event->find('all', array('contain' => array('Date' => array('conditions' => array('Date.date >=' => date('Y-m-d'))))));
```

It's possible to do that with Cakephp find method? Thanks.

Comment: It's not via the `find` but [Hash::sort](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::sort) could be used. For example: assigning your `find` to $results then `$resultsort = Hash::sort($results,'{n}.Date.{n}.date', 'asc');`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```
$this->Event->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Date' => array(
            'conditions' => array('
                Date.date >=' => date('Y-m-d')
            )
        )
    ),
    order => array(
        'COUNT(Date.id)' => 'DESC'
    )

));
```

Comment: I got the following error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Date.id' in 'order clause'.
Tried to move the order to 'Date' contained but still gives me the same order.

Comment: `order` should be entered as `'order'` but I think `GROUP_BY` might be more appropriate here

Comment: Yes I fixed the 'order' while testing. 
But the problem is that 'Date.id' is not a member from Event table. What if I try a join instead of a contain? Will it maybe help?

Comment: Use the primary key of the table